# Calculating offset for HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am tracing a point in an HTML5 video using canvas overlay. The canvas is on top of the video tag with the following style:

```
#my-canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; position:absolute !important; z-index:100000; margin: 0 auto; background-color:rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.0); }
```

The points were captured via separate (Android) app. Here's how I plot the points on the canvas:

```
MyClass.prototype.drawLine = function(_context, _ctr, _color) {
    _context.lineWidth      = 2;
    _context.lineJoin       = 'round';
    _context.strokeStyle    = _color;

    _context.moveTo(this.data["xs"][_ctr]*this.xOffset, this.data["ys"][_ctr]*this.yOffset);
    _context.lineTo(this.data["xs"][_ctr+1]*this.xOffset, this.data["ys"][_ctr+1]*this.yOffset);
    _context.stroke();
    _context.closePath();
}
```

I multiply the data points with an offset value to compensate for the screen size. This is how I calculate the offset:

```
MyClass.prototype.calculateOffsets = function() {
        this.yOffset        = this.video.offsetHeight/parseFloat(this.data["height"]);
        this.xOffset        = this.video.offsetWidth/parseFloat(this.data["width"]);
}
```

This code works fine in a landscape video but not in portrait. I might be missing something with the offset calculation. I would appreciate if you can point me to the proper direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you set canvas size using CSS your canvas will actually always be 300x150 pixels. What you draw to it will be relative to that size.

Try instead to remove the 100% width and height from the CSS rule and set the canvas size for its bitmap every time you get an onresize event etc. CSS sets the *element* size; this will set the *bitmap* size (element will follow if no CSS is overriding):

```
_context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
_context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

and

`#my-canvas {`<strike>`width: 100%; height: 100%;`</strike>`position:absolute`...

Notice though that changing the canvas size will also clear it so you will have to redraw everything up to that point if that is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I follow. Probably I didn't express my situation clear enough, I apologise for that. 

The problem with my code is that the points I plot on the canvas is in sync if the video is in landscape mode. If it's in portrait, it's off.